# Why does "if 0 <= Points >= 50:" always trigger?

Tags: python

Why does it always returns with "Congratulations! You have won a wooden rabbit!"?

It seems that `x` and `y` values don't change.

```
def which_prize(Points):
    y=1
    if 0<= Points >=50 :
        x="wooden rabbit"
    elif 151<= Points >=180 :
        x="wafer-thin mint"
    elif 181<= Points >=200 :
        x="penguin"
    else:
        y=0
    re="Congratulations! You have won a {}!".format(x)
    if y==0 :
        re= "Oh dear, no prize this time."

    return re

#print(which_prize(51))
print(which_prize(151))
print(which_prize(181))
print(which_prize(200))
print(which_prize(18000))
```

Comment: format the code please

Comment: All the `>=` on the right should be `<=`

Comment: `0<= Points >=50` is true if `Points` is greater than or equal to 0 _and_ greater than or equal to 50. That's probably _not_ what you meant. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `if` block is true for every `Point` bigger than or equal to 50.

`if 0 <= Points >= 50:`

A working example:

```
def which_prize(Points):
    y = 1
    x = ''
    if 0 <= Points <= 50:
        x = "wooden rabbit"
    elif 151 <= Points <= 180:
        x = "wafer-thin mint"
    elif 181 <= Points <= 200:
        x = "penguin"
    else:
        y = 0

    re = "Congratulations! You have won a {}!".format(x)

    if y == 0:
        re = "Oh dear, no prize this time."
    return re


print(which_prize(51))
print(which_prize(151))
print(which_prize(181))
print(which_prize(200))
print(which_prize(18000))
```

will print:

```
Oh dear, no prize this time.  
Congratulations! You have won a wafer-thin mint!  
Congratulations! You have won a penguin!  
Congratulations! You have won a penguin!  
Oh dear, no prize this time.
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl Working code as [schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/schwobaseggl) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
def which_prize(points):

    prize = None
    if 0 <= points <= 50:
        prize = "a wooden rabbit"
    elif 151 <= points <= 180:
        prize = "a wafer-thin mint"
    elif 181 <= points <= 200:
        prize = "a penguin"

    if prize:
        return "Congratulations! You have won " + prize + "!"
    else:
        return "Oh dear, no prize this time."

print(which_prize(51))
print(which_prize(151))
print(which_prize(181))
print(which_prize(200))
print(which_prize(18000))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is better solution:

```
points = 199

if points <= 50:
    result = "Congratulations! You won a wooden rabbit!"
elif points <= 150:
    result = "Oh dear, no prize this time."
elif points <= 180:
    result = "Congratulations! You won a wafer-thin mint!"
else:
    result = "Congratulations! You won a penguin!"

print(result)
```

Output:

```
Congratulations! You won a penguin!
```